# Event Listeners listening after being removed

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a lot of event listeners in my class, and earlier I asked how do I kill these listeners after they happen once, and I had that issue solved.

It works in some cases, but in others I am having issues. So for example, I have this method that has an event listener.

```
    private void startGame() {
    HomePage.getCurrentGameID(new HomePage.CallbackID() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(final String currentGameID) {
            games.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    if (dataSnapshot.child(currentGameID).getValue().equals(1)) {
                        getResults();
                        Log.i("FlipCoin", "``startGame() happened");
                    } else {
                        return;
                    }
                    games.removeEventListener(this);
                }
}
```

I have that method that starts the game, and at the end of the `onDataChange()` I have `games.removeEventListener(this)`. But sometimes, even after this is executed, it still runs the code and I know this because it Logs to the LogCat every time the method happens.

There is only one instance in my code where I call `startGame()`, and that instance is in this timer

```
private void runCounter() {
    final Runnable counter = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
                Log.i("FlipCoin", "``runCounter() happened");
                startGame();
            }
        }
    };
    counter.run();
}
```

I got rid of a lot of unnecessary code, so these methods may not make a lot of practical sense, but they are being used as examples for my problem.

Anyways, as you can see in the runCounter() method, it calls `startGame()` like it should, and I also have a log in the method that lets me know when this `runCoutner()` method is called.

The weird thing is the `runCounter()` method is only logged once in the logcat like it should be, but it keeps logging `startGame()`, even though I only call it once in my code, and I remove the listener at the end of the method.

Why is this happening, I am super confused!

---

Runnable I am using (not relevant to the question)

```
private void runCounter() {
    final TextView headsOrTails = findViewById(R.id.HeadsOrTails);
    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    final AtomicInteger n = new AtomicInteger(3);
    final Runnable counter = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            headsOrTails.setText("Flipping in: " + Integer.toString(n.get()) + " seconds");
            if (n.getAndDecrement() >= 1)
                handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
            else {
                headsOrTails.setText("Flipping");
                Log.i("FlipCoin", "``runCounter() happened");
                startGame();
            }
        }
    };
    counter.run();
}
```

Comment: You should probably add log before `addValueEventListener` to know if it is being added more than once. According to this code, and if `removeEventListener` is implemented correctly, this should not happen.

Comment: Why are you not using `addListenerForSingleValueEvent`, whose whole purpose is to listen only once?

Comment: Also your Runnable in runCounter is completely unnecessary.  You'll get exactly the same effect if you just call startGame().

Comment: @DougStevenson There are some issues that come with converting it to `addListenerForSingleValueEvent`, and if you would have read my post thoroughly you would know I got rid of code to simplify the problem, the Runnable does have a purpose.

Comment: I'm very curious to know what practical purpose this Runnable serves, and now it behaves compared to not having it at all.  You typically only use a Runnable in conjunction with a new thread, or some thread pool or executor.  And I'm also very curious to know why addListenerForSingleValueEvent doesn't work for you, because it's a core feature of the SDK.  It should not have problems if you use it correctly.

Comment: This runnable is pointless. He probably thinks it is creating a new thread when it doens't... the only thing this runnable does is create a variable scope what could be done with `{}`

Answer (score 0):

You are using it wrong.

If you want to listen to the value just once and than remove the listener use: `addListenerForSingleValueEvent`

Comment: it means your code is calling that method more than once

Comment: There is only one spot in my code, I have looked through it many times, that the method is called. And the Runnable that is calling the method, is also only called once.

Comment: you having just one call in the code doesn't mean that code isn't called many times... you could start organizing your code that is really messy than you will eventually find the bug.  you create many `Runnable` and execute them in the same thread... this is pointless. And is a bad practice to create unecessary annonymous classes. Plus there is no explanation to what `new HomePage.CallbackID()` does... you use a `get` method and pass something as parameter... it is agains basic code desing

Comment: if with all changes you still cant realise why is being called mulpletimes, simple debug and look at stack trace which method is calling it

Comment: Like I said in my post I have taken out a lot of code just to simplify the problem down to the core. None of the code that looks pointless is actually pointless.